# Integration by parts, unclear point.

Tags: integration, functions

I'm trying trying to find $\int{\frac{1}{x\ln{x}}}$ for $x \gt 0$

Let's try integration by  parts.
Let:
$$u = \frac1{\ln{x}}, u' = -\frac{1}{x\ln^2{x}}$$
$$v' = \frac1{x}, v = \ln{x}$$
Then:
$$\int{\frac{1}{x\ln{x}}} = uv -\int{u'v} = 1 + \int{\frac{1}{x\ln{x}}} \Rightarrow 0 = 1$$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: Constant of integration.

Comment: @NigelOvermars So C must be $-1$ then?

Comment: Yes, only then you have an inequality.

Comment: @NigelOvermars Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using u-substitution with $u=\ln x$, not integration by parts.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is an option, but why does the integration by parts gives us that result? $0$ obviously not equals $1$, but I can't tell where I was mistaken.

Comment: Probably because the function in the integral is the result of a chain rule deriviative, not a product rule derivative. Either way, you should use u-substitution.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a definite integral,

$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{x\ln x}=\left.1\right|_a^b+\int_a^b\frac{dx}{x\ln x}$$

and the World is safe.

Answer (score 0):

1. Substitute $u=\ln(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\mathcal{I}(x)=\int\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u=\ln\left|u\right|+\text{C}=\ln\left|\ln(x)\right|+\text{C}$$
2. Using integration by parts $\int f(x)g'(x)\space\text{d}x=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\mathcal{I}(x)=\int\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{x}\int\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\space\text{d}x-\int\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot\int\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\space\text{d}x\right)\space\text{d}x$$
3. Using integration by parts $\int f(x)g'(x)\space\text{d}x=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\mathcal{I}(x)=\int\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x-\int\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right)\cdot\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\right)\space\text{d}x$$

For (3) you find:

$$\mathcal{I}(x)=\int\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\cdot\ln|x|-\int\left(-\frac{1}{x\ln^2(x)}\cdot\ln|x|\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{\ln|x|}{\ln(x)}+\int\frac{\ln|x|}{x\ln^2(x)}\space\text{d}x$$

Comment: I think you can leave off the absolute values in (3), since you know that $x>0$ because $\ln x$ is defined.

Comment: Yes matje that is true nut this is not a full answer :)

Answer (score 0):

no need to use Integration by parts.Simple substitution will do.
$\int\frac{dx}{xlogx}$ put $u=logx$ and $du=\frac{dx}{x}$ substitute this
$\int \frac{du}{u}$ on integrating $log(u)+C=log(logx)+C]$

Answer (score 0):

**Indefinite** integration by parts is:
$$
\int {d(uv)}  = \int {d(uv + c_0 )}  = uv + c_0  = \int {u\,dv}  + \int {v\,du}  = \int {u\,d\left( {v + c_1 } \right)}  + \int {v\,d\left( {u + c_2 } \right)} 
$$